# Setting friction params

Tags: friction

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ok guys, is any of you open to explain this in a simplified matter, or on a specific example?
We all usually need friction for wheels; so If you have a wheel, turning on the **x** direction. You would want to have friction on the **x** direction. and on the **y** also so the wheel does not slip on the sides. So **mu = mu2**. But if you want to model an **omniwheel**, you would like the y direction to have no friction, so the wheel can actually slip that side. So you set up the **mu2 = 0** In case your wheel is not oriented on the specified axes you can change the direction with **fdir1**.

I keep on seing people advising friction of 100 or some other values that are not comprised in the **0..1** interval specified by the **sdf documentation**. What is the catch with that?

I played around with the friction, but apparently for the same settings, my wheels react differently from a run to another.

I try to simulate a 3 omniwheeled robot base.
And I've just come to realise there is no friction in the sdf code generated for gazebo from the xacro file written.

code URDF:

```
<surface>
    <friction>
      <ode>
        <mu>1</mu>
        <mu2>0</mu2>
        <fdir1>0 1.0 0</fdir1>
        <implicit_spring_damper>true</implicit_spring_damper>
      </ode>
    </friction>
  </surface>
```

generated code SDF with gw sdf -p:

```
  <surface>
      <contact>
        <ode>
          <kp>1e+06</kp>
          <kd>1</kd>
        </ode>
      </contact>
      <friction>
        <ode/>
      </friction>
    </surface>
```

A part of my question can be also found [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1512/what-do-the-friction-coefficients-mean-and-why-are-they-so-large-in-the-drcsim-atlas-urdf-files/), but nobody actually answered that part.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16343/setting-friction-params/) by [SorinV](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3291/sorinv/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-06-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Very important: **fdir = direction of mu1 in the collision local reference frame**

SO i was setting the friction all wrong because i have some wheels that are not all oriented on the same angle so i was calculating a different fdir for each one when there was no need because the reference is local so all you need is either x or y of the fdir to be set to 1 depending on how you build the wheels.
I bypassed the generation issue by modifying and loading directly the sdf file using gazebo_ros/spawn_model:

```
<arg name="robot_xdf_description" default="$(find MY_PACKAGE)/urdf/robot.sdf" />
<node name="sdf_spawner_1" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model"
            args="-z 1.0 
            -unpause 
            -sdf 
            -model robot1 
            -file $(arg robot_xdf_description) 
            -robot_namespace /robot1" 
            respawn="false" output="screen" />
```

**EDIT**
On a second thought i realised the frame is not the local one (see this [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/545/request-change-contact-reference-frame)), but the fdir does not work in the global frame.

**EDIT2** Indeed I was right. The fidir still does not work for all the cases. See [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2068/directional-friction-still-broken).

---

Originally posted by [SorinV](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3291/sorinv/) with karma: 41 on 2017-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3879/josephcoombe/) on 2018-09-12**:
At least according to the Bitbucket issue (https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2068/directional-friction-still-broken), the issue is resolved as of 2017/09/11.

**Comment by [yuril](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/23075/yuril/) on 2020-03-05**:
do you manage to get the wheels right? if so could you show me how?